# An Abelan quotient ring by Socle

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring with identity whose (right) socle $S$ contains its nilpotent elements. Is it necessarily true that the quotient $R/S$ is an abelian ring? ( By an abelian ring I mean a ring whose idempotents are central.) 
For example, $R$ may be a reduced ring -such as a domain-which does trivialy satisfies the hypothesis.
Thanks for any answer!